# Full height columns with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**http://jsfiddle.net/ww7dN/**

I'm trying to design a page that is "split" in 2 colors all the way down (green on the left, blue on the right). In each section I want to put a column. First problem is that the colors don't fill the whole page. Second problem is that when I resize the page the horizontal scrollbars don't appear.

What am I doing wrong? Or do you have a better way to achieve this effect?

If this is complicated with CSS, I won't mind a jquery solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `#container` had no position so its children didn't know who('s shoes) to fill...

http://jsfiddle.net/ww7dN/1/

try adding to #container:

```
#container {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;width:100%;
  left:0;top:0;
}
```

---

For your second question, change`overflow:hidden` to `overflow:auto;` to the container you want to scroll horizontally.

**Update from your comment**
Try adding

```
BODY {
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

to your `body`'s css

Comment: Thanks but I can't get the scroll bar to appear. I just want it to appear normally like for any page.

Comment: I noticed that if I give #container a min-width I can get it to appear. Is that a good way to do it.?

Comment: change the overflow to overflow:scroll if you want it to always appear

Comment: @Cris I'm not sure what you mean... If its about the scrollbar, google `css overflow` and find a w3 example. `overflow:hidden` **hides** the scrollbar.

Comment: Here's what I mean. The content gets cut off instead of a scrollbar appearing on the bottom of the browser. http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/534/contentcutoff.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try changing below CSS like this:

```
#public {
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
color:#fff;
}
#public #container {
height:100%;
}
```

Also,
overflow: hidden prevents the scrollbar to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Give a position:absolute to left div;